# Action of $C*$ on a vector space V being equivalent to a grading

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

I'm currently reading the paper "NOTES ON GIT AND SYMPLECTIC REDUCTION FOR
BUNDLES AND VARIETIES" by R. P. Thomas, on the last part of page $2$ he writes (and I quote) "Now we just do everything $\mathbb{C}^∗$-equivariantly. Recall that a $\mathbb{C}^∗$-action on a vector space $V$ is equivalent to a grading, i.e. a splitting into subspaces (the eigen- or weight spaces) $V_k$ parameterised by the integers (the eigenvalues or weights).", I don't seem to understand why this is an equivalence, after some thought my guess was that if we define:
$$V_k := \{v \in V | c.v=c^kv\}$$
These $V_k$ are linearly independent and in the case where $V$ is the vector space of polynomials we have:

$$V = \bigoplus_{i} V_i$$

Hence I tried to prove it in general, I reached the following:

we can imbed $\mathbb{C}^*$ into $GL(V)$ and these elements commute hence the matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable and with a change of basis we may assume that the action changes the coefficient of basis elements by a scalar

here I'm stuck and can't move forward, also it is clear that given a grading we can define the action as I have written.
Any help is appreciated.